# symfony submitting to link table entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've been staring at this too long, and now I need another set of eyes.

I had previously set up my relationship between two entities, Dish and Ingredient as a many to many relationship, and had the form association working perfectly.   However, I realized afterward that I needed another field on my link table to specify "amount" so as a result I created a new entity DishIngredient.   It created the same table but instead of a many to many, it's now one table with two Many to One relationships to Dish and Ingredient.

So far so good.  I have everything working until I attempt to associated ingredients with dishes.   I'm able to successfully generate a form to display each of the Ingredients, however when I submit it, I run into problems.   It's attempting to submit to Ingredient instead of DishIngredient.

Here is what I have so far:

My controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/recipe/ingredient/{id}", name="edit_ingredients")
 */
public function ingredientEdit(Request $request, Dish $dish, $id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $dish_id = $dish->getId();
    $dish = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Dish::class)->findOneBy(array('id' =>$dish_id ));

    $dish_user = $dish->getUser();
    //in case someone tries to manually hack into someone else's recipe
    if($dish_user != $user) {
        return $this->render('dishes/error.html.twig', array(
                'dish' => $dish,
                'user' => $user
            )
        );

    }
    else {
        $form = $this->createForm(IngredientType::class, $dish);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $dish = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($dish);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('edit_ingredients', array('id' => $id));

        }
        return $this->render('dishes/ingredients.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'dish' => $dish
            )
        );

    }
}
```

Which then loads this form:

```
class IngredientType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        $ingredient = new Ingredient();

        $builder
            ->add('DishIngredients',EntityType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                'class' => Ingredient::class,
                'query_builder' => function(IngredientRepository $ir) {
                    return $ir->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))


            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Update',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary mt-3')
            ))
            ->getForm();

    }

}
```

It displays fine in the twig with the following:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {% for i in form.DishIngredients %}
    {{ form_widget(i) }} {{ form_label(i) }}<br>
     {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

However the problem is that when I attempt to submit it, I get this error:

> Expected value of type "App\Entity\DishIngredient" for association
>   field "App\Entity\Dish#$dishIngredients", got "App\Entity\Ingredient"
>   instead.

If I change the form to call DishIngredient instead of Ingredient, it shows none of the ingredient; it just creates a text field looking for an input;  not what I want or need at all.

Here's the DishIngredient Entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DishIngredientRepository")
 */
class DishIngredient
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Dish", inversedBy="dishIngredients")
     */
    private $dish;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ingredient", inversedBy="dishIngredients")
     */
    private $ingredient;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $amount;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDish(): ?Dish
    {
        return $this->dish;
    }

    public function setDish(?Dish $dish): self
    {
        $this->dish = $dish;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIngredient(): ?Ingredient
    {
        return $this->ingredient;
    }

    public function setIngredient(?Ingredient $ingredient): self
    {
        $this->ingredient = $ingredient;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAmount(): ?string
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function setAmount(?string $amount): self
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and here's the Ingredient entity for reference

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\IngredientRepository")
 */
class Ingredient
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\DishIngredient", mappedBy="ingredient")
     */
    private $dishIngredients;


    public function __toString(): ?string
    {
        // TODO: Implement __toString() method.
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dishes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->dishIngredients = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }


/**
 * @return Collection|DishIngredient[]
 */
public function getDishIngredients(): Collection
{
    return $this->dishIngredients;
}

public function addDishIngredient(DishIngredient $dishIngredient): self
{
    if (!$this->dishIngredients->contains($dishIngredient)) {
        $this->dishIngredients[] = $dishIngredient;
        $dishIngredient->setIngredient($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeDishIngredient(DishIngredient $dishIngredient): self
{
    if ($this->dishIngredients->contains($dishIngredient)) {
        $this->dishIngredients->removeElement($dishIngredient);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($dishIngredient->getIngredient() === $this) {
            $dishIngredient->setIngredient(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}}
```

Anyone have any ideas here?

--
EDIT:

Okay, so I created a new form titled DishIngredientType, and moved the information from above into it, and then modified IngredientType to have following instead:

```
    $builder
        ->add('DishIngredients',CollectionType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
            'entry_type' => DishIngredientType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],

        ))
```

but now I'm only getting a plan text field (no options at all).

This is how they look in DishIngredientType

```
        ->add('DishIngredients',EntityType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
            'class' => Ingredient::class,
            'query_builder' => function(IngredientRepository $ir) {
                return $ir->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
            },
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ))
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  I know this shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: That's because now you need to treat DishIngredient as whole Entity instead of just association. This can be done in two parts, create dish, create ingredients and add them to dish, that creates association. You are still adding ingredients to dish via form, which should be done in code rather than via form.

Comment: Hi @MaulikParmar, okay,   I already can add dishes and can add ingredients;  that's still working fine from before - they are entered separately via form.   I do, however still need a form to associate the dish with the ingredients.  I already have this set up - it shows exactly as I need:  a list of checkboxes with each of the ingredients - it's already attached to dish via id.    I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "code rather than via form"  - I still need an interface for the user to add ingredients to a dish?  Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: As you can see in your `IngredientType`, the form builder has DishIngredients as EntityType which is not true, it's a collection of `DishIngredient` class, also it is fetching `Ingredient::class`. Thus when submitting your form, your entity is expecting DishIngredient while it's getting instance of Ingredient. To solve this, I'd recommend you to see the first comment and start treating it as Entity. You need to have another form type called `DishIngredientType` which connects dish and ingredient - check  [Embedding Form Collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: @MaulikParmar okay I've tried building a new form as you suggest, and calling it as a collection, but I'm not getting any positive results; it only returns an unclickable single text field, not the array of checkboxes I need.   I've edited my question above.    Maybe you can see an obvious mistake I've made?

Comment: Your `DishIngredient` is composite type, you need to Make `IngredientType` collection and then map it to `DishIngredientType` when persisting that collection, think front-end Forms as Dish having collection of `IngredientType`, when you persist, you actually create `DishIngredient` entity, set current dish and selected `Ingredient`. Forms does not have to follow internal mappings, that is why they are separated. Your mapping entity has nothing to do with form, except relating those entities.

Comment: @MaulikParmar I don't suppose it would be possible for you to demonstrate what you mean? I'm having a hard time grasping this ( I switched around the forms so that I'm calling DishIngredientType first, and then calling IngredientType as an entity) but now I'm having trouble with the controller;  it can't find through the ParamConverter annotation.    I feel like an example might help me understand better, because I think I have to start from scratch